# Cannot save sets with chrome.storage.local.set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have been having difficulties trying to save sets using chrome.storage.local.set.

I have tested enclosing the set in an object literal, hoping that it would save since objects seem to be savable but it did not work. Somehow it actually works on firefox, but fails on chrome.

```
let test = new Set(["a","b","c"]);
console.log(test);
chrome.storage.local.set({testing: test}, function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["testing"], function(item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

console.log(item) prints out the key-value associated with testing, but there is nothing in it, the set wasn't saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the data is serialized in order to be stored

> Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex (serialize using their String representation).

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

To fix that, you can convert the `Set` to an array when you store it and then back to a `Set` when you retrieve it.

Here is an example:

```
let test = new Set(["a","b","c"]);
console.log(test);
chrome.storage.local.set({testing: [...test]}, function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["testing"], function(item) {
        if (item.testing) {
            const retrievedTest = new Set(item.testing);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok I suspected something like this, thanks for confirming and the fast reply!